# How to sort an array which has factors as ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)), according to each of lengths in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to sort an array which has factors as ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) and represents both of edges of a line, according to each of lengths in Julia. 
I cannot write because of dim-difference between Python and Julia.
In Python, lines are sorted like follows;

```
lines = [ ((l[0][0], l[0][1]), (l[0][2], l[0][3])) for l in lines ]
lines.sort(key = lambda l: -sqrt((l[0][0]-l[1][0])**2+(l[0][1]-l[1][1])**2))
```

How to write the same process in Julia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want this:

```
lines = [((a,b), (c,d)) for (a,b,c,d) in lines]
```

or this

```
lines = [((a,b), (c,d)) for (a,b,c,d) in eachrow(lines)]
```

(I would need an example of input `lines` and expected output example to be sure)

In order to sort it just use `by` kwarg:

```
sort!(lines, by=(((a,b), (c,d)),) -> -sqrt((a-c)^2+(b-d)^2))
```

or

```
sort!(lines, by=x -> -sqrt((x[1][1]-x[2][1])^2+(x[2][1]-x[2][2])^2))
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot writing the sorting process.

Comment: added the `sort!` example